# Carousel only works once in a Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I'm building a Bootstrap modal with some data from a Json file. 
I'm trying to include a carousel with images inside the modal. The carousel is an [Owl carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)

I got things working as it should work. However the carousel only works the first time you open a the modal. The second time you open any modal the carousel doens't work. Does somebody have experience with this? Or what could cause this?

My code:

```
if(product.images.length >= 2){
  var wqsImages = [];
  $.each(product.images, function(index, wqsThumb){
    var thumb = 'image_id_convert(wqsThumb) + '/70x70x2/image.jpg';
    var wqsImage = $('<div class="item"><a href="'+wqsThumb.url+'" class="fancybox-thumb" data-fancybox-group="group1" title="'+product.title+'"><img src="' + thumb + '" width="70" height="70" data-featured-url="'+image+'" data-original-url="'+image+'" alt="'+product.fulltitle+'" />');
   wqsImages.push(wqsImage);        
  });
  wqsImages.join('');

  ////// ONE WAY I TRIED, SO DIRECTLY FIRE OWLCAROUSEL /////

  $('.wqs-content .product-image-slider').html(wqsImages).owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    itemsDesktop : [1199,5],
    slideSpeed: 600,
    autoPlay: 5000,
    stopOnHover: true,
    navigation: false,
    pagination: false,
    autoHeight : true
  }).data('navigationBtns', ['#product-image-slider-prev', '#product-image-slider-next']);

////// OTHER WAY I TRIED, SO FIRST APPEND CONTENT AND AFTER THAT START OWLCAROUSEL //

$('.wqs-content .product-image-slider').html(wqsImages);

 var wqsThumbSlider = $('.wqs-content .product-image-slider.owl-carousel');
  wqsThumbSlider.owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    itemsDesktop : [1199,5],
    slideSpeed: 600,
    autoPlay: 5000,
    stopOnHover: true,
    navigation: false,
    pagination: false,
    autoHeight : true
  }).data('navigationBtns', ['#product-image-slider-prev', '#product-image-slider-next']);*/
}
```

Anybody? Thx in advance...

Comment: Did you check for errors? What is `product`? How does the `HTML/CSS` look like? Can you reproduce the issue in something like a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)??

Comment: @TJ: I've made a fiddle here -> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/mdxha9fd/) It's not fully working but now you have an idea what I mean

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with having owl carousels inside Bootstrap modals, now fixed.

I'm assuming that you have multiple owl carousels in the DOM that can be selected and then played within a modal.

The reason why beyond the first showing that the owl carousel doesn't show again, is because the JavaScript is later confused as to which carousel instance it should essentially "reinitialize".

**Solution**: Specify the carousel instance in the modal specifically, rather than targeting ".owl-carousel" that targets all instances.

For example: On modal show and carousel init (first and all subsequent)...

Change

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({...});
```

To something like

```
$('.js-modal .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({..});
```